# How to get vertical Z axis in 3D surface plot of Matplotlib?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting some data as a 3D surface plot using Matplotlib. The code I am using is pretty similar to this [3D surface plot example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html). It generates the plot shown below:

[image]

The problem with this plot is that the Z-axis is not vertical. How do I make the Z-axis vertical?

I examined the different API available and found [view_init](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init). By setting a low elevation (`elev=1`) of the plot using `view_init`, I can get the Z-axis to be vertical, as shown below:

[image]

However, the problem here is that at low elevation the Y axis tick labels are all overwritten and cannot be viewed correctly. So I need the plot to be at a high elevation and with the X-Y plane rotation angle as shown in Figure 1. How do I achieve a vertical Z-axis for this plot?

I do not know Matlab, but I know Matplotlib is derived from the Matlab API. So, I looked at surface plot examples in Matlab documentation and found that the Z-axis seems to be vertical in their examples. One figure for illustration with high elevation is shown below:

[image]

**Update 1:** Based on Bentoy13's suggestion, I set `view_init(elev=30, azim=-37.5)` and got the below result. It is better, but not yet vertical:

[image]

In comparison, Z-axis in Matlab plot is perfectly vertical. Also, as is visible from this angle, I cannot actually use this `azim=-37.5` since some information is hidden. Any other solution? :-)

Comment: It looks like perpertive projection/ortographc proyection problem

Answer (score 3):

In MPL 2.1.0[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAIQ.png) they added the option to manually override the projection to generate your 3d graph with an orthographic projection; simply insert the following line into your script:

```
ax.set_proj_type('ortho')
```

[Example from MPL source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAIQ.png)]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAIQ.png) https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html

Answer (score 2):

In the examples given in the Matlab documentation, surface plots are often viewed in a special position which is given by the command `view`:

```
view(3)
```

The command [`view`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/view.html) sets the viewpoint of the axes. According to the doc, `view(3)` sets the default three-dimensional view with azimutal = –37.5 and elevation = 30.

**EDIT**

The problem of having a vertical z-axis is not that the axis is vertical, but is a problem of perspective. By default, Matlab plots 3D surfaces with a orthographic projection, but matplotlib seems to draw with perspective projection. Sadly matplotlib doesn't provide an API for setting this...

**EDIT 2**

It appears that the following patch is very useful to draw 3D in orthographic projection:

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
def orthogonal_proj(zfront, zback):
    a = (zfront+zback)/(zfront-zback)
    b = -2*(zfront*zback)/(zfront-zback)
    return numpy.array([[1,0,0,0],
                        [0,1,0,0],
                        [0,0,a,b],
                        [0,0,0,zback]])
proj3d.persp_transformation = orthogonal_proj
```

I take no credit for this patch, you can find it [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/537).

Comment: Thanks! I tried those settings and the Z-axis is better, it is almost vertical. I have updated the question with the new figure. Any way to make it perfectly vertical, like in Matlab figure? Also, I cannot use this azim for this data :-)

Comment: @Ashwin see my edit. I found a piece of code to turn to orthographic projection [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/537), but I'm not familiar with matplotlib so I don't know how you can use it once you've drawn your surface plot.

Comment: Bentoy13: That worked! Can you repost that code snippet as an answer, so I can accept it? :-)

Comment: As of version 2.1 this feature is implemented: https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html#orthographic-projection-for-mplot3d